# How do I name these classes under the BEM methodology?

Tags: bem

Image below is the output of my code
[image: output]

Are these names correct under BEM methodology?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__button-row--1">
        <div class="button-row__button--first"></div>
        <div class="button-row__button"></div>
        <div class="button-row__button"></div>
        ...
        <div class="button-row__button--last"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container__button-row--2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `.container` a Block or part of your grid?   
Modifiers should be added like `<div class="foo foo--modifier">`  
Over all you have to decide is this on Block or several Blocks ?

Comment: @anderssonola it will be a block, as a component, so I will have possible multiples of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sample code in your question I'd suggest the following. But I would also point out that `container` is a bad name for a component/Block since it really general and does not indicate the purpose of the Block.

For modifiers you should use both the element and the modifier in the class attribute e.g. `block__element block__element--modifier`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__button-row container__button-row--1">
        <div class="container__button container__button--first"></div>
        <div class="container__button"></div>
        <div class="container__button"></div>
        ...
        <div class="container__button container__button--last"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container__button-row container__button-row--2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My apologies, new to SO